# Complex Linq-To-Entities query with deferred execution: prevent OrderBy being used as a subquery/projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I built a dynamic LINQ-to-Entities query to support optional search parameters. It was quite a bit of work to get this producing performant SQL and I am *NEARLY* there, but I stumble across a big issue with OrderBy which gets translated into kind of a projection / subquery containing the actual query, causing extremely inperformant SQL. I can't find a solution to get this right. Maybe someone can help me out :)

I spare you the complete query for now as it is long and complex, I translate it into a simple sample for better understanding:

I'm doing something like this:

```
// Start with the base query    
var query = from a in db.Articles
            where a.UserId = 1;

// Apply some optional conditions
if (tagParam != null)
    query = query.Where(a => a.Tag = tagParam);

if (authorParam != null)
    query = query.Where(a => a.Author = authorParam);

// ... and so on ...

// I only want the 50 most recent articles, so I finally want to apply Take and OrderBy
query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.Published);
query = query.Take(50);
```

The resulting SQL strangely translates the OrderBy in an container query:

```
select top 50 Id, Published, Title, Content
from (select Id, Published, Title Content
      from Articles
      where UserId = 1
      and Author = @paramAuthor)
order by Published desc
```

Note that also the Top 50 got moved to the outer query. In case I would only use Take(50), the top 50 sql statement would correctly be applied to the inner query above (the outer query wouldn't even exist). Only when I use OrderBy, Linq-To-Entities uses this container query approach.

This causes a very bad execution plan where the inner query takes all articles that apply to the parameters from Disk and pass them to the outer query - and only there, OrderBy and Top is processed. In my case, this can be hundred thousands of lines. I already tried to move the order by manually into the inner statement and execute this - this produces much better results as the existing indexes allow the SQL Server to easily find the top 50 rows in right order without reading all rows from disk.

Is there any way I can get EF to append the order by clause to the inner query? Or any other trick to get this working right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit:** As an additional information, some tests with less complex queries showed that the Optimizer normally handles such subquery scenarios well. In my scenario, the Optimizer fails on this unfortunately and moves hundrets of thousands of rows through the query plan. But moving the OrderBy to the inner query solves it and the Optimizer does it right.

**Edit 2:** After couple of hours of more testing it seems the issue with the wrong execution plan is a SQL Server issue that is not caused by the created container query. While the move of the order by and top clause into the inside query did fix the issue initially, I can't reproduce this now anymore, SQL Server started using the bad execution plan now also here (while the data in the DB remained unchanged). The move of the order by clause might caused SQL Server to take other statistics into account but it seems it was not due to the better/more clean query design. However, I still want to know why EF uses a container query here and if I can influence this behavior. If it will not improve performance, at least it would make debugging easier if the generated EF queries are more straightforward and not that convoluted.

Comment: The subselect is created by the sql server EF Provider and can therefore not be changed. You could modify the statement with a command interceptor, but this involves lots of manual query parsing and I would not recommend this. Nevertheless it should not have any impact on the performance as the SQL Query optimizer optimizes the subselect away. In this case I think you are simply missing a suitable index and/or statistics that allows the Sql Server to produce an optimized execution Plan.